# Character level RNN for converting word forms

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, language-models

I want to build a char RNN to convert word form from one to another, for example, singular nouns such as `lion` to `lions`. However all I could find related to char RNNs is about creating language models and generating random text (and I'm unsure how this is helpful).

Can anyone guide me how this can be done, as in how exactly am I supposed to train a RNN on this kind of data? I'm using Tensorflow, so a similar project would be wonderful